# how can I know I have access to this state in this function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

for my edit profile page I need to call 2 APIs for change profile picture. I used `fetch()`.
the way APIs works is at first I send user id, and expect a response that is a number for upload id.
and then I send that id to the next API as a name for the image.
also I store my base64 image to a sate and the second API doesn't work properly because I assume that I can not access to the image state in this function.
I cant console log the image inside the function it gave me this:

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
```

here is my implementation for this:

```js
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [imageUploading, setImageUploading] = useState(false);
  const [uploadId, setUploadId] = useState('');
  const userData = useSelector(state => state.user.userData)

  const logOutHandler = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('loginData').then(() => {
        props.navigation.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [{ name: 'Login' }]
        })
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    console.log('Done.')
  }

  const allowAccess = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
      const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      } else {
        pickImage()
      }
    }
  }

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      base64: true
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.base64);
      uploadImage()
    }
  };

  const uploadImage = () => {
    
    fetch('URL',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "id": userData.id
          })
      })
      .then(response => response.json()) // pass the data as promise to next then block
      .then(data => {
        setUploadId(data)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))

      
        fetch('URL2',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
              "fileName": uploadId,
              "fileBase64String": image,
              "folderName": 'User',
              "fileExtension": '.jpg'
            })
        })
        .then(response => response.json()) // pass the data as promise to next then block
        .then(data => {
          console.log('here....' ,data)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }
```

Comment: Another thing I would recommend is you make 2nd  API synchronous. Since the API's are dependent, move the fetch("For 2nd API") within the then block.

Comment: @KaranGaur Thanks for the response, it give me error :  "errors": Object {
    "": Array [
      "Failed to read the request form. Form key length limit 2048 exceeded.",
    ],
  },
  "status": 400,
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "traceId": "|9776e7a3-4a9998d0c78f9ed8.",
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
}

Comment: Try using multipart as content-type header - "multipart/form-data"

Comment: No luck, Object {
  "status": 415,
  "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "traceId": "|9776e7a9-4a9998d0c78f9ed8.",
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
}
also I console log as order of calls, but it seems they run buy order.

Comment: multipart must only be used for the second API Call. Also could you shed more light on the backend as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow two steps:-

1. Try removing headers from fetch api
2. Instead of application/json value for content-type in headers add application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   ```
   headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
   ```

Comment: "Failed to read the request form. Form key length limit 2048 exceeded.",